# On close fancybox child iframe I want to update my textbox value on the parent screen without reloading parent

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a form in page 1 (the parent page) and when user press a radio button then and fancybox Iframe Page (the child) appears in which I am getting a value after processing.

I want to pass that value to a parent page 1  after closing of page 2 without reloading it coz I don't want my user to re-enter the form value but I just want to show that value in any format, It could be a textbox or message printed in div.

Thanks

Comment: Show us the code inorder to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `onClosed` eventhandler see http://fancybox.net/api

```
$("a#fancybox").fancybox({
  'onClosed': function (){
     /* Whatever you want to do */
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What i beilieve you want to do is pass data from the child iframe to the parent. You can refer this article : http://www.roseindia.net/java/pass-value-example/pass-value-from-iframe-parent.shtml for the same. Hope it helps!